# signed apk is not working but unsigned apk is working for G+ and FB integration

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, unsigned, signed

App is  integrated with Google and Facebook login only. If APP is run in debug mode(straight from device), it works perfectly fine(able to login with Google or Facebook) but when the app is signed(release mode), Google and Facebook login integration stopped working.

Error comes in SigninActivity.java on -

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Name :"+acct.getDisplayName()+" Email :"+acct.getEmail(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        Toast.makeText(this,"Signed out ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

handleSignInResult is coming false.

```
Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
```

Debug apk runs on the device and signed(release) apk not runs on the device.
App is running but google and facebook integration not working. But on some devices fb integration working only not google. And on my device(4.4.2) neither fb nor google working

Comment: issue is in your key store.
Which key store are you using?

Comment: I use existing keystore which used for older version of app. I also create new keystore to check my fault but same problem exists.

Comment: kindly user debug key store.

Comment: debug.keystore apk still not working

Comment: any error, you are getting?

Comment: debug apk not even run - Unfortunately, app has stopped

Comment: what error you have got in LogCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use debug keystore with password = "android".
You can find your debug keystore in .android folder.
**Example** : C:\Users\shoeb.android

Comment: Yes, I do the same thing

Comment: debug.keystore doesnot show any logcat and signed apk shows error with G+ integation: Error signing in the specified acc. Plz choose different acc but not with unsigned apk

Comment: Thanks to give me way